# How to implement recursive all possible combination of any set (JAVA)

Tags: java, arraylist, set, combinations, theory

Can someone give me a few clues or help with writing a combination function where it would output all possible combination of a set. I have an idea. But I find it hard.

Something like this in Java.

```
String set[] = {"Java","C++","Python"};

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public void combination(String[] set) {

    if (set.length == 0) {

       do nothing

    } else if (this a combination from the set) {
       add to the list
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you sure you need combinations, or is it permutations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of combinations of all letters in a String, just to give you an algorithm.  See if you can transfer the algorithm to your example.

```
    public class StringLib {

    public static void combine(String str){
        int length=str.length();

        StringBuffer output=new StringBuffer();

        combination(str,length,output,0);
    }

    static void combination(String str, int length, StringBuffer output, int level){
        /* show arms-length recursion style with better peformance */
        if (level==length)
            return;
        else{
            for(int i=level;i<length;i++){
                output.append(str.charAt(i));
                System.out.println(output.toString());
                combination(str,length,output,i+1);
                output.deleteCharAt(output.length()-1);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        combine("abc");
    }
}

/*Output:

a
ab
abc
ac
b
bc
c
*/
```

Just in case you actually need permutations:

```
import java.util.*;

public class permutations
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str = new String("abc");
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    boolean used[] = {false, false, false};

    permute.printPermutations(0, output, used, str);
  }
}


public class permute{

  static void printPermutations(int level, StringBuffer output, boolean used[], String orig){
      int len = orig.length();
      if (level == len){
          System.out.println(output);
      }
      else{
          for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){    
              //recurse if not used already
              if (!used[i]){
                  output.append(orig.charAt(i));
                  used[i] = true;
                  printPermutations(level+1, output, used, orig);
                  output.deleteCharAt(output.length() - 1);
                  used[i] = false;
              }
          }
      }
  }
}




/*Output:

abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba

*/
```